# How do I format a Date in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, date-formatting

I could be overlooking something, but Flash / AS3 seems to be missing basic date formatting functionality. How do I get a formatted string from a `Date` ? There's a few options like `.toLocaleDateString()` and `.toUTCString()`, but that a bit limiting, to say the least.

So, how do I format a `Date` object in AS3?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like the date formatted?

Comment: yes, although I don't really think it matters, since a decent dateformatter should be able to handle all sorts of custom format.

I currently want a date formatted like this:
`2010-09-16T07:28:14+00:00` >>
`2010.1609.0728`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Flash Player 10.1 added a DateTimeFormatter as part of the flash.globalization package. It's flexible but not well documented.

```
import flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter;

var d:Date = new Date();
var dtf:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("en-US");
dtf.setDateTimePattern("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' hh:mm:ssa");
trace(dtf.format(d)); 

// 2012-06-06 at 09:58:46PM
```

Comment: you can also just throw in a handy constant for the first arg on the DateTimeFormatter constructor:

`new DateTimeFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT);`

Comment: 24-hour format: `dtf.setDateTimePattern("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: Docs here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of a custom format:

```
    public static function getDateIso8601Long(date:Date):String {
        var str:String = date.getFullYear().toString()
        str = str +"-"+ ((String((date.getMonth()+1)).length == 1)?"0"+(date.getMonth()+1):(date.getMonth()+1)).toString()
        str = str +"-"+ ((date.getDate().toString().length == 1)?"0"+date.getDate():date.getDate()).toString()
        str = str +"T"+ ((date.getHours().toString().length == 1)?"0"+date.getHours():date.getHours()).toString()
        str = str +":"+ ((date.getMinutes().toString().length == 1)?"0"+date.getMinutes():date.getMinutes()).toString()
        str = str +":"+ ((date.getSeconds().toString().length == 1)?"0"+date.getSeconds():date.getSeconds()).toString()
        var ms:String = date.getMilliseconds().toString()
        while (ms.length < 3)
            ms = "0"+ms
        str = str+"."+ms
        var offsetMinute:Number = date.getTimezoneOffset()
        var direction:Number = (offsetMinute<0)?1:-1
        var offsetHour:Number = Math.floor(offsetMinute/60)
        offsetMinute = offsetMinute-(offsetHour*60)

        var offsetHourStr:String = offsetHour.toString()
        while (offsetHourStr.length < 2)
            offsetHourStr = "0"+offsetHourStr
        var offsetMinuteStr:String = offsetMinute.toString()
        while (offsetMinuteStr.length < 2)
            offsetMinuteStr = "0"+offsetMinuteStr
        str = str+((direction == -1)?"-":"+")+offsetHourStr+":"+offsetMinuteStr
        return str 
    }
```

Comment: I was kinda hoping not to have to invent my own wheel.

Comment: Maybe look at different util class available in large framework/libraries(as3coreLib,Spring Actionscript1). I'm not certain of what you would like to do. Do you need only formatter or also calculator? A simple google search returned me many Actionscript 3 utility classes for Date calculation. Also, converting a Java date utility class to As3 would be trivial.

http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/utils/DateUtil.as

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you are overlooking anything in terms of native support. There is [this project](http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/) which seems to offer a bit more flexibility, however I have not ever got round to working with it in any depth so I can't vouch for it. The project I am currently working on has a 500 line (and counting) DateUtil class as a result..

Answer (score 1):

There is the `mx.formatters.DateFormatter` class (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html). It has a `formatString` property for custom formatting. You can then call `format`, supplying a Date to get a string.

Comment: It's worth noting that DateFormatter is part of the Flex framework and is not available to vanilla Flash projects unless you include the appropriate Flex libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static function getTime():String
{
    const d = '.';
    const e = '';
    const s = ':';

    var date:Date = new Date();
    return e.concat(pad(date.hours, 2), s, 
                    pad(date.minutes, 2), s, 
                    pad(date.seconds, 2), d, 
                    pad(date.milliseconds, 3));

    function pad(value:String, length:int):String
    {
        const zero = '0';
        var result:String = value;
        while (result.length < length)
        {
            result = zero.concat(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```